# Is "put" imperative in this sentence?

Tags: past-participles, imperatives

In a writing exercise I sent to my English teacher, she wrote some comments evaluating my writing. Some comments were about what I did, and others were about what I should do. In the sentences about what I should do she used the Imperative form. But, one of the sentences was this one:

> Put a touch of personal feeling in
>   your conclusion.

The problem is that the word "Put" can be Preterit, Past Participle or Present Participle. So, how can I know if "Put" was used as a Preterit or to build an Imperative clause?

Comment: I think you mean “present”, not “present participle”. The present participle of *put* is *putting*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has to be an imperative; if it were preterit, it would have a subject (“You put a touch of …”).

Comment: Yep. It's important to remember that the imperative is the *only* place in English where you can omit the subject (outside of very informal registers), so if the subject is missing then it must be imperative.

Comment: @JSBangs  Good point. I remembered that the Imperative form has an understood "you", but I didn't had notice that it's the only kind of sentence in which the subject is omited.

Answer (score 4):

With a lot of English phrases, the purpose of a word is implied by its context. In this case, it an order, so it would have to be imperative.